# Customizing left/rightmark fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am trying to typeset a document in the style of AMS Graduate studies in mathematics series. Follow the link for an example:

http://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-154/18

In particular, I am trying to mimic the headings. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmarginratio=1:1,margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{\baselineskip}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\cfoot{}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\textsl{\thechapter.\ #1}}{}}
%\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\textsl{\thesection.\ #1}}{}}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}\thechapter}
\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\begin{document}
 \chapter{some chapter}
  \section{some section}
\end{document}
```

This almost works as intended, except that the section title is in all caps. If I try to use the same code I used for the chapter title (i.e. the line commented in my MWE), then the section title just disappears from the headings. 
What I would like to do is simply to have the section title in slanted normal font (not all caps), like the chapter.

Comment: You need `\markright` instead of `\markboth` for the sectionmark: `\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\textsl{\thesection.\ #1}}}`

Comment: thank you. It worked. If you post this as an answer I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `\markright` instead of `\markboth` for the sectionmark:

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\textsl{\thesectio‌​n.\ #1}}}
```

This will set the `\rightmark` without disturbing the `\leftmark` of the chapter.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not stuck with `fancyhdr` it is very simple with `titleps` , which comes with `titlesec` but can be used independently. It doesn't require struggling with marks:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmarginratio=1:1,margin=1.2in]{geometry}
%%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} needless since parskip is loaded
\usepackage{parskip}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{titleps}
\newpagestyle{mine}{%
\setheadrule{1pt}
\headrule%]
\sethead[\thepage][][\slshape\thechapter.\enspace\chaptertitle]{\slshape\thesection. \enspace\sectiontitle}{}{\thepage}
\setfoot{}{}{}}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{mine}

\begin{document}

 \chapter{Some Chapter}

 \lipsum[1]
  \section{Some Section}
\lipsum[2-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]